# C - Realloc Fails because "enot enough space"

Tags: c, realloc

iam actually failing on a realloc. Perror returns a "not enough space" message, which i cant really explain myself.

I compile with Mingw32 on W10. No Optimizions(with -wall, wextra).

Its for simple snake game. Iam step for step implenting some functions. Actually i wanne simple grow up snake. ( Snake got a Head Block, and some Body Blocks).

At Init, i allocate 5 Snake Blocks with malloc.
SNAKE_START_BLOCKS is 5 per #define

My definition for a Block:

```
// Structs
typedef struct {
    float x;
    float y;
    float w;
    float h;
} Block;
```

Here:

```
GameSnake.SB_Body = malloc(SNAKE_START_BLOCKS * sizeof(Block));

    if(GameSnake.SB_Body == NULL)
    {
        printf("Game Subsystem Fehler 'GameSnake': Kann Speicher fuer Blocks nicht laden!\n");
        return false;
    }

    size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i<SNAKE_START_BLOCKS; i++)
    {
        GameSnake.SB_Body[i].w = SNAKE_PICTURE_SIZE;
        GameSnake.SB_Body[i].h = SNAKE_PICTURE_SIZE;
        GameSnake.SB_Body[i].x = GameSnake.SB_Head.x - (((float)i*(float)SNAKE_PICTURE_SIZE/Level.TL_X_Size)+(float)SNAKE_PICTURE_SIZE/Level.TL_X_Size);
        GameSnake.SB_Body[i].y = GameSnake.SB_Head.y;
    }

    GameSnake.SB_Body_Elements = SNAKE_START_BLOCKS;
```

Some Codeline later, if i got a hit to my food. I Call my Grow Function

```c
// Lets grow the Snake..
bool CSFMLGrowSnake()
{
    GameSnake.SB_Body = realloc(GameSnake.SB_Body, (GameSnake.SB_Body_Elements+1) * sizeof(Block));

    if(GameSnake.SB_Body == NULL)
    {
        printf("Game Subsystem Fehler 'GameSnake': Kann keinen zusaetzlichen Speicher fuer die Snake anfordern!\n");
        perror("Genauer Fehler: ");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        GameSnake.SB_Body[GameSnake.SB_Body_Elements].w = SNAKE_PICTURE_SIZE;
        GameSnake.SB_Body[GameSnake.SB_Body_Elements].h = SNAKE_PICTURE_SIZE;

        // Check Direction and Setup the new Block
        // Todo: Prevent New Block appears in tile Border/in Snake/in Item
        if(GameSnake.S_Actual_Direction == UP)
        {
            GameSnake.SB_Body[GameSnake.SB_Body_Elements].x = GameSnake.SB_Body[GameSnake.SB_Body_Elements-1].x;
            GameSnake.SB_Body[GameSnake.SB_Body_Elements].y = GameSnake.SB_Body[GameSnake.SB_Body_Elements-1].y + (float)SNAKE_PICTURE_SIZE/Level.TL_Y_Size;
        }
        else if(GameSnake.S_Actual_Direction == DOWN)
        {
            GameSnake.SB_Body[GameSnake.SB_Body_Elements].x = GameSnake.SB_Body[GameSnake.SB_Body_Elements-1].x;
            GameSnake.SB_Body[GameSnake.SB_Body_Elements].y = GameSnake.SB_Body[GameSnake.SB_Body_Elements-1].y - (float)SNAKE_PICTURE_SIZE/Level.TL_Y_Size;
        }
        else if(GameSnake.S_Actual_Direction == RIGHT)
        {
            GameSnake.SB_Body[GameSnake.SB_Body_Elements].x = GameSnake.SB_Body[GameSnake.SB_Body_Elements-1].x - (float)SNAKE_PICTURE_SIZE/Level.TL_X_Size;
            GameSnake.SB_Body[GameSnake.SB_Body_Elements].y = GameSnake.SB_Body[GameSnake.SB_Body_Elements-1].y;
        }
        else if(GameSnake.S_Actual_Direction == LEFT)
        {
            GameSnake.SB_Body[GameSnake.SB_Body_Elements].x = GameSnake.SB_Body[GameSnake.SB_Body_Elements-1].x + (float)SNAKE_PICTURE_SIZE/Level.TL_X_Size;
            GameSnake.SB_Body[GameSnake.SB_Body_Elements].y = GameSnake.SB_Body[GameSnake.SB_Body_Elements-1].y;
        }

    }

    GameSnake.SB_Body_Elements++;

    return true;
}
```

I checked up my array indices. But that seems ok.
Then i checked Element Adresses at Initialization:

```
Pointer Adress[0]: 40900000
Pointer Adress[1]: 40800000
Pointer Adress[2]: 40600000
Pointer Adress[3]: 40400000
Pointer Adress[4]: 40200000
```

Which confuse me a bit, is that "decreasing" of Adress normal?! Should it be reversal?

Sometime it works, but if it works, after a few seconds, it leads to segmentation fault. If i print addresses in my grow functions, the newest element will have an adress of 0.

But in Most cases, it directly fails on the realloc, with the
perror message "not enough space".

Iam actually unsure where the problem is. Maybe you can help me or give me a tip. I cant believe that additional 16 Bytes will overflow my memory :O

I have a repo at github, if you want to view the whole file here is it:
https://github.com/MasterOfPenetrator/SnakeGame/blob/master/CSFMLGameSnake.c

Every help is welcome !

Thanks in advance!

**Some Details from the Debugger**

```
Disassembly:
At this line it breaks:
0x4045b4    mov    0x41026c,%eax
0x4045b9    add    $0x1,%eax
0x4045bc    shl    $0x4,%eax
0x4045bf    mov    %eax,%edx
0x4045c1    mov    0x4101d0,%eax
0x4045c6    mov    %edx,0x4(%esp)
0x4045ca    mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x4045cd    call   0x40b900 <realloc>

Debugger says:
Failure finding "Stack level "
Failure matching reg_output

This is the content of the adress
0x41026c: 05 00 00 00 59 6f 75 72|65 20 43 6f 6f 6c 21 00    ....Youre Cool!.
0x41027c: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00|64 00 00 00 0e 01 00 00    ........d.......

which is setted in my init here
strcpy(GameSnake.S_Name, "Youre Cool!");

The structure is here:
typedef struct {
    Block SB_Head;
    Block *SB_Body;

    sfTexture *SB_Head_Texture;
    sfShader *SB_Head_Shader;
    sfRenderStates SB_Head_State;
    sfTexture *SB_Body_Texture;
    sfShader *SB_Body_Shader;
    sfRenderStates SB_Body_State;

    size_t SB_Body_Elements;
    char S_Name[50];

    int S_Health;
    int S_Rotate;
    int S_Score;

    float S_Speed;
    float S_DefaultSpeed;
    float S_LightDistance;
    bool S_Light_FBM;
    bool S_Light_OnOff;

    Direction S_Actual_Direction;
    Direction S_Prev_Direction;

    bool S_Is_Init;
    bool S_Is_Dead;

    bool S_GODMODE;
    bool S_NOCLIP;

    float S_EndItemTime;

} Snake;
```

And now iam confused...

**UPDATE**

I found the error, shame on me :(,
In my PopBlocks Function i did the horrible fail:

```
for(i = GameSnake.SB_Body_Elements; i>0; i--)
            /\
            ||
I should append a "-1", now it works fine ;)
```

Iam wondering how long a illegal access work ;-)
This Function is called by every move ;)

thanks for help!!

Comment: Edit: Hi folks! , in my question that greeting was ignored :S

Comment: You must check `errno` (which is where `perror` is getting the error from) *directly* after the failure. After the `printf` call the value of `errno` is indeterminate.

Comment: Run ina debugger.  When it breaks print `GameSnake.SB_Body_Elements`

Comment: I don't know how the use of MinGW affects this, but when running 32 bit MSVC compilation on Windows 7 or 10 the total amount of memory (static + dynamic) available to the program is less than 2Gb.

Comment: ERRNO says ENOMEM, i never reach 2GB, at RAM i got about 20MBs, VRAM is ~50MB(iGPU).

Comment: Are you leaking memory?

Comment: I'll checked, and all mallocs are free'ed.